# Node.js - Diagnose "(node) warning: Recursive process.nextTick detected."

Tags: javascript, node.js, stack-overflow

My application has a situation in which an operation takes a very long time to complete, and then a couple hundred instances of the following message is printed:

```
(node) warning: Recursive process.nextTick detected. This will break in the next version of node. Please use setImmediate for recursive deferral.
```

And then the application crashes with:

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

No stack trace.

How do I diagnose such errors? I'd like to know, for instance, which function call preceded the `RangeError`.

To replicate the error, run `node foo.js` on the file `foo.js` with the following contents:

```
var foo = function () {
    process.nextTick(foo);
};
foo();
```

I am not so much interested in the particular cause of this problem in my application as I am in knowing how to diagnose this type of problem in node.

Node version is `v0.10.39`.

Comment: `node --trace foo.js > trace.log` may get you somewhere, but I doubt it's usable in the context of a real app as it will probably introduce too many side-effects.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `process.nextTick` to print some sort of useful information – something along the lines of:

```
var _nextTick = process.nextTick;
var alreadyLogged = new Set();

process.nextTick = function nextTick(f) {
    if (!alreadyLogged.has(f)) {
        alreadyLogged.add(f);

        process.nextTick = _nextTick;
        console.log(f);
        process.nextTick = nextTick;
    }

    return _nextTick.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this solves the issue.  This would block the recursion, but not log what was causing it?  And, it doesn't log when there's a recursive call detected.  And, the second time you call `process.nextTick()` with the same function passed, it will be blocked then too because the `Set` is never cleared.  This seems to be an interesting direction, but less than half implemented.

Comment: @jfriend00: Sorry, that was just a mistake. It’s not intended to block recursion; just to log any function passed at most once.

Comment: I tried this, but in my application, I got "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" on startup. Some other function `function () { afterWrite(stream, state, finished, cb); }` got logged a bunch of times when I switched to logging the `toString` value of `f`.

Comment: @Jackson: Sorry, try the updated version; `console.log` uses `process.nextTick`, so the original has to be restored when using it.